# Force added plot (with different axes) to have the same origin in R

Tags: r, plot

Consider I have a plot like this:

```
par(mar=c(3,5,1,5))
X=rnorm(10)
Y1<-rnorm(10)
Y2<-rnorm(10)*10+2
plot(X,Y1,col=2,ylab="red")
points(0,0,pch=3,,col=2,cex=2)
```

and an additional plot added to that:

```
par(new=T)
 plot(X,Y2,col=4,axes=FALSE,ylab="")
 points(0,0,pch=4,col=4,cex=2)
 axis(side=4)
 mtext("blue",4,2)
```

Is there a way to make the origin of both plots allign with each other?

I tried setting the `xlim` and `ylim` values as max of the input variables to center the plot but that only creates a lot of free space with skewed plots.

It doesn't matter if the second plot is not fitted perfectly but it shouldn't be cut off. It rather should scale accordingly.
Also, because it is part of a larger code I would prefer answers for r base graphics.

EDIT:
Another possibility would be to create a factor p

```
p<-min(range(Y1)/range(Y2))
```

and then plot `points(Y2*p~X,col=4)` without calling `par(new=TRUE)`
But then I would have to create an axis scaled by factor `p`. And I can't get that working either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I was almost there.
Quite dodgy, so any comments on how to nice it up are welcome.

EDIT:a little less dodgy

```
par(mar=c(3,5,1,5))
X=rnorm(10)
Y1<-rnorm(10)
Y2<-rnorm(10)*10+2

#then I create the scale factor 

p<-signif(min(range(Y2)/range(Y1))*2,1)/2

#then I add the original and scaled second plot and axis:

plot(X,Y1,col=2,ylab="red",ylim=c(min(c(Y1,Y2/p)),max(c(Y1,Y2/p))))
points(0,0,pch=3,,col=2,cex=2)
points(X,Y2/p,col=4)
points(0,0,pch=4,col=4,cex=2)
axis(4,at=axTicks(4),labels =axTicks(4)*p)
mtext("blue",4,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the same `ylim` as `min` and `max` of the Y variables for both plots

```
plot(X,Y1,col=2,ylab="red", ylim=range(c(Y1,Y2)))
points(0,0,pch=3,,col=2,cex=2)

par(new=T)
plot(X,Y2,col=4,axes=FALSE,ylab="", ylim=range(c(Y1,Y2)))
points(0,0,pch=4,col=4,cex=2)
axis(side=4)
mtext("blue",4,2)
```

Comment: Yes I know. But that is not what i wanted. I wouldn't need a second Y axis then. Consider the case, that Y2 is an order of magnitude bigger than Y1, then the points for Y1 are represented only as a line. I want the Y2 axis to be scaled accordingly. Thanks anyway